# How do I subscribe to an event from the ViewModel in the MainWindow?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, inotifypropertychanged

I'm trying to figure out how to subscribe to an event that's firing in my ViewModel from my MainWindow.xaml.cs.

ViewModel:

```
public class LoginViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isAuthenticatedUser;
    public bool IsAuthenticatedUser 
    {
        get { return isAuthenticatedUser; }

        set
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Old value:" + isAuthenticatedUser);

            isAuthenticatedUser = value;
            Debug.WriteLine("New value:" + isAuthenticatedUser);

            OnNotifyPropertyChanged("IsAuthenticatedUser");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnNotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Property Change on LoginView.IsAuthenticatedUser");
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    private int? oldUnreadTextsCount = 0;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeTimer();
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    public TextsViewModel TextsViewModel { get; set; }
    public LoginViewModel LoginViewModel { get; set; }
    public MainWindowViewModel MainWindowViewModel { get; set; }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();

        // First Subscribe;
        LoginViewModel.PropertyChanged += UserAuthentication_PropertyChange;

        // Second Fire Change / Fire update on UserAuthentication_PropertyChange.
        LoginViewModel.TestAuthentication();

        // Third Change Views appropriately
        if (LoginViewModel.IsAuthenticatedUser)
        {
            NavigationFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new HomeView());

            TextsViewModel = new TextsViewModel();
            TextsViewModel.PropertyChanged += UnreadTexts_PropertyChanged;
        }
        else
        {
            NavigationFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new LoginView());
        }
    }

    private void UserAuthentication_PropertyChange(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("PROPERTY CHANGE REGISTERED:MainWindow:Checking if logged in.");

        if (LoginViewModel.IsAuthenticatedUser)
        {
            Header.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Footer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Debug.WriteLine("Logged In");
        }
        else
        {
            Header.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            Footer.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            Debug.WriteLine("Logged Out");
        }
    }
}
```

It would seem all I need to do is in my NOTIFYING CLASS (ViewModel):

- Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`
- Add the `public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;`
- Add the `OnNotifyPropertyChanged("IsAuthenticatedUser");`
- Add the following method to my notifying class:

```
protected void OnNotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Property Change on LoginView.IsAuthenticatedUser");
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

---

Then in my SUBSCRIBING class (MainViewWindow) add the following:

- Subscribe to the event in my ViewModel `LoginViewModel.PropertyChanged += UserAuthentication_PropertyChange;`
- Add the method that is referenced in the subscription like the one below

```
    private void UserAuthentication_PropertyChange(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("PROPERTY CHANGE REGISTERED:MainWindow:Checking if logged in.");

        if (LoginViewModel.IsAuthenticatedUser)
        {
            Header.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Footer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Debug.WriteLine("Logged In");
        }
        else
        {
            Header.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            Footer.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            Debug.WriteLine("Logged Out");
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. The subscribed method `UserAuthentication_PropertyChange` is ONLY fired once when the application first starts and there is a change in the value of the `IsAuthenticatedUser` Property on the ViewModel. Why doesn't this work every time there is a change?

For more information if you can help me understand this phenomenon (to me) here's a quick run down of what gets printed to the console as the app runs and I trigger login and logout sequences.

Start the app - Currently logged out.

```
TestAuthentication:LoginViewModel:False
Old value:False
New value:False
Property Change on LoginView.IsAuthenticatedUser
PROPERTY CHANGE REGISTERED:MainWindow:Checking if logged in.
Logged Out
```

Yay! It looks like its working... but wait - there's more...

Then I log in

```
AuthenticateUser:LoginViewModel:True
Old value:False
New value:True
Property Change on LoginView.IsAuthenticatedUser
```

The property change is fired but the MainWindow no longer hears it... Why wouldn't it?

Comment: How do you actually login? I see the `DataContext` is the `MainWindowViewModel`. So how do you trigger the log in logic of the `LoginViewModel`. Right now, it looks like you are operating on two instances of  `LoginViewModel`. You only listen to the events of the instance you created in the `Loaded` handler, but when you login you are using a different maybe XAML instance of `LoginViewModel`?

Comment: Yes that's correct, when I create the login page using `NavigationFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new LoginView());` I instantiate a new LoginViewModel in that page's codeBehind. Is having 2 instances of this what's causing the issue?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am saying. You only subscribed to `PropertyChanged` of one instance. This instance is not the same you are using for the real login via the login page. Another sideeffect would be that both view models have a different state. If `IsAuthenticatedUser` is `true`in one instance then it is still `false` in the other. You definitely don't want this. Make sure you are using only one instance of every view model, except you deliberately want to have multiple instances - but in this case you want a shared/reused instance.

Comment: Hmm. This makes a ton of sense and something I didn't consider before. The state would obviously be changed from instance to instance. How would you recommend sharing my ViewModels? I could inject this ViewModel in this case and probably be fine but what about other cases? Is there a way to make each instance of ViewModel globally accessible? For example I can pass in the `LoginViewModel` instance into my navigation method because this is the only place I really need access to it from - but that wont always be true. I need to have my `TextViewModel` accessible for several places.

Comment: Also would you put that as an answer so I can accept it. I've tested it and you nailed the problem!!! Thank you so much for helping me understand this!!!

Comment: Does `TextViewModel` has to be accessible from other views only or also from other view models?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212647/discussion-between-jay-and-bioniccode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, it looks like you are operating on two instances of LoginViewModel. You only listen to the events of the instance you created in the Loaded handler, but when you login you are using a different maybe XAML instance of LoginViewModel.

To answer your question, how to handle the view models, I suggest to replace the `Frame` with a `ContentControl`.
This requires that each view has its own view model e.g. LoginViewModel --> LoginView, HomeViewModel --> HomeView. Furthermore must be each view defined inside a `DataTemplate`.
A `ContentControl` binds to the `SelectedPage` property and renders the page by applying the appropriate `DataTemplate`.

Navigation now takes place inside the view model by setting a `SelectedPage` property of the `MainWindowViewModel` to the view model of the page you wish to navigate to.
This way you can move the navigation to the view model and can comfortably handle events etc, since the view model has knowledge of other view models when using composition (or aggregation).

**PageName.cs**
Enumeration to eliminate magic strings as page identifiers in XAML and C#.
Can be used as `CommandParameter` when used e.g. with a `Button.Command` to navigate to a certain page.

```
enum PageName
{
  LoginView, HomeView
}
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{  
  public TextViewModel TextViewModel { get; set; }
  private Dictionary<PageName, object> Pages  { get; set; }

  private object selectedPage;   
  public object SelectedPage
  {
    get => this.selectedPage;
    set 
    { 
      this.selectedPage = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private bool isAuthenticated;   
  public bool IsAuthenticated
  {
    get => this.isAuthenticated;
    set 
    { 
      this.isAuthenticated = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public MainWindowViewModel()
  {
    // Alternatively use constructor injection

    var loginPageViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
    loginPageViewModel.AuthenticationStatusChanged += OnAuthenticationStatusChanged;

    this.Pages = new Dictionary<PageName, object>()
    {
      { PageName.LoginView, loginPageViewModel },
      { PageName.HomeView, new HomeViewModel() }
    }

    // Show login screen initially
    this.SelectedPage = Pages[PageName.LoginView];

    this.TextViewModel = new TextViewModel();
  }

  // Example ICommand execute action, triggered e.g. on Button.Command,
  // where the CommandParameter is a value of the PageName enumeration
  private void ExecuteNavigateToPage(object commandParameter)
  {    
    if (commandParameter is PageName pageName
      && this.Pages.TryGetValue(pageName, out object pageViewModel)
    {
      this.SelectedPage = pageViewModel;
    }
  }

  private void OnAuthenticationStatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {    
    this.IsAuthenticated = (sender as LoginViewModel).IsAuthenticatedUser;

    // Redirect to main page when user has authenticated successfully        
    if (this.IsAuthenticated)
    {
      this.SelectedPage = Pages[PageName.HomeView];
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**LoginViewModel.cs**

```
public class LoginViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{  
  public event EventHandler AuthenticationStatusChanged;    
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private bool isAuthenticatedUser;   
  public bool IsAuthenticatedUser
  {
    get => this.isAuthenticatedUser;
    set 
    { 
      this.isAuthenticatedUser = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged();

      OnAuthenticationStatusChanged();
    }
  }

  private void OnAuthenticationStatusChanged()
  {
    this.AuthenticationStatusChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

** MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
  private int? oldUnreadTextsCount = 0;

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    InitializeTimer();

    var mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    DataContext = mainWindowViewModel;

    mainWindowViewModel.TextsViewModel.PropertyChanged += UnreadTexts_PropertyChanged;

    Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
  }

  private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    // Navigation (and debugger output) has been moved to the MainWindowViewModel.
    // Toggling of the visibility has been moved to XAML using DataTrigger
  }
}
```

**LoginView.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="LoginView">

  <!-- 
    DataContext is automatically the LoginViewModel, 
    accessible from code-behind via the DataContext property 
  -->
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsAuthenticatedUser}" />
</UserControl>
```

**HomeView.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="LoginView">

  <!-- 
    DataContext is automatically the HomeViewModel, 
    accessible from code-behind via the DataContext property 
  -->
  <TextBlock Text="Welcome back user!" />
</UserControl>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type LoginViewModel}">
      <LoginView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type HomeViewModel}">
      <HomeView />
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Header">
      <TextBlock.Style>
       <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />

         <Style.Triggers>
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAuthenticated}" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
           </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
      </TextBlock>
    </TextBlock>

    <!-- 
      Page host. Setting the content to a page view model,
      will automatically load the corresponding DataTemplate
    -->
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedPage}" />

    <TextBlock x:Name="Footer">
      <TextBlock.Style>
       <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />

         <Style.Triggers>
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAuthenticated}" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
           </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
      </TextBlock>
    </TextBlock>
</Window>
```